# How to save PendingIntent that is used to create an alarm to use later in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I use PengingIntent to create an alarm in android application.
The question is how do I save it so it would be possible to use it in alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent) method call even after the app has been closed and reopened again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the same pending intent again with the same code and use it to cancel, make sure the code to create pending intent is the exact same code

Comment: happy to help!!